# Nmap showing all host up

Tags: nmap, port-scanning

I am trying to use "NMAP", to conduct a port scan for hosts in my LAN. The problem is NMAP is showing all hosts are up, most of the host does not exist in my LAN. I am using NMAP 6.47 in VMWARE with NAT configuration.

Note: In bridge mode, NMAP works fine, but I have to work in NAT mode.

I am against brick wall right now, I have reinstalled VMWARE workstation again, but somehow getting the same problem.

Comment: Can you include output of `nmap -d --packet-trace -n -sn` against some non-existent host which is incorrectly reported as up? If not here, we would appreciate a bug report at http://issues.nmap.org/new

Comment: This question appears to be [off topic](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic).